# Amazon S3 Download: Direct iOS or Web Service Node Js.?

Tags: ios, mysql, node.js, amazon-s3

I'm creating an ios app that connects to a backend Node js web service. The applications allows users to upload pics which is handled via AFnetworking and my node js backend up to mysql(filepath) and amazon S3(actual image). However, for downloading the pics into a uitableview, i'm want to know if it would be better to handle the download over the backend with a post request and return the pic from the backend or handle everything on the client side and load the pictures using the aws-sdk. Both processes would of course be handled asynchronously with me first getting the objects from the mysql database and then using the filename as the key to return the image. Which would be a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.

**Original Idea**

I would suggest setting up a redirect on your node.js server. So the device hits your server and gets the redirect and downloads from AWS. I believe you could do this for uploads too [**EDIT:** Nope upload wouldn't work because redirects would cause the POST to become a GET I think (need to do some research)].

That way if you could switch away from AWS to a different host without updating your app. But if your more concerned about performance then flexibility go download directly from AWS.

**New Answer**

Upload and Download directly to the AWS server. What I've done in the past, however, is provide all the AWS params like the AWSAccessKeyId, policy, signature, ... to client from the server in a JSONDict called AWSParams, and the client takes those params and send them on in the upload request.

Comment: how would that redirect work exactly, don't I still have to provide the necessary credentials and parameters to the amazon node module in order to upload or download a file? Or if not, how would I redirect my iOS request straight to amazon S3?

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about it a bit more. Redirect wouldn't work on anything other than a GET request, so I don't think you could that when uploading. So ignore my answer, because of the upload part. Probably best to just go directly to the server, since there is no way of isolating upload process.

Comment: @brianScroggins  Thanks for catching the issue with the upload redirect. I should have double-checked how redirect change non-GET requests.

Comment: @brianScroggins oh I found out that a 307 redirect should cause the client to POST with the same information at the new location, but implementation is spotty. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect